# How can I learn about the availability of daily or higher frequency data?

Tags: high-frequency-data, nowcasting, midas-models, mixed-frequency-regression

I am interested in the process of nowcasting--updating forecasts of economic activity based on data at the daily frequency or higher Several of the Feds produce daily nowcasts of the GDP. But the only daily frequency data I am really familiar with are securities and commodity prices. Are there daily series on economic activity beyond prices? If so, who publishes such series? I know some people have gained access to total credit card purchases at high frequency.  Does anyone know of such series, whether from credit cards or otherwise, that are available to an individual researcher without the backing of a famous university?